# How to start socket.io like foreground service to stay connected and listen for messages

Tags: android, socket.io, android-service, foreground-service

I am using this source app to chat with other devices. But how to make it to start like a Service so I can to start foreground service.
Do I need MainFragment and LoginActivity rewrite in Service?

socket.io app [socket.io-android-chat](https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-android-chat)

I have tried something like that in class SocketService, what other I need to include in Service for App to get notification messages even if app is closed.

```
public class SocketService extends Service {
    private Socket mSocket;
    public static final String TAG = SocketService.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID_DEFAULT = "App running in background";
    String GROUP_KEY_WORK_EMAIL = "com.android.example.WORK_EMAIL";
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this, "on created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setGroup(GROUP_KEY_WORK_EMAIL);
        Notification notification = builder.build();
        NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigTextStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
        // Set big text style.
        builder.setStyle(bigTextStyle);
        startForeground(3, notification);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "start command", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try {
            mSocket = IO.socket(Constants.CHAT_SERVER_URL);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        mSocket.on("newMessageReceived", onNewMessage);
        mSocket.connect();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private Emitter.Listener onNewMessage = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
            String username;
            String message;
            try {
                username = data.getString("username");
                message = data.getString("message");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                return;
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "call: new message ");
            setNotificationMessage(message, username);
        }
    };

    public void setNotificationMessage(CharSequence message, CharSequence title) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        builder.setContentTitle(title);
        builder.setContentText(message);
        NotificationManagerCompat nm = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        nm.notify(3, builder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: have you got solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

you shouldn't use a foreground service  in order to get notification messages when your app is in the background

instead you should use [firebase push notification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging)

however if you still need to use the socket connection in your foreground service

just simply create a singleton class to handle all socket connection and use it your foreground service as shown below

```
 public class SocketManger {


        private  static SocketManger socketManger;

        Socket socket;
        Callback<Boolean> onConnect;

        public void init(Callback<Boolean> onConnect){
            this.onConnect = onConnect;
            connectToSocket();
            listenToPublicEvents();
        }

        private void connectToSocket(){
            try{
                IO.Options opts = new IO.Options();
                //optional parameter for authentication
                opts.query = "token=" + YOUR_TOKEN;
                opts.forceNew = true;
                opts.reconnection = true;
                opts.reconnectionDelay = 1000;
                socket = IO.socket(YOUR_URL, opts);
                socket.connect();

            }
            catch(URISyntaxException e){

                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

        private void listenToPublicEvents(){
            socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, args -> {
                if(onConnect!=null)
                    onConnect.onResult(true);
                    } );

            socket.on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, args ->{
                    if(onConnect!=null)
                    onConnect.onResult(false);
                   });
        }


        public void emit(String event, JSONObject data, Ack ack){
            socket.emit(event, new JSONObject[]{data}, ack);
        }


        public void on(String event, Emitter.Listener em){
            socket.on(event, em);
        }


        public static SocketManger getSocketManger() {
            if(socketManger == null){
                socketManger = new SocketManger();
            }
            return socketManger;
        }


        public boolean isConnected(){
            return socket!=null && socket.connected();
        }

        public void onDestroy() {
            onConnect = null;
            socket.disconnect();
        }

    public interface Callback<T> {
      void onResult(T t);
     }

    }
```

and add this code to your foreground service

```
SocketManager socketManger = SocketManger.getSocketManger();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
      socketManger.init(this::onSocketEvent);
   }

 public void onSocketEvent(boolean connect){
    //your code when the socket connection connect or disconnect
    }
```

and make sure to disconnect the socket when the service is destroyed

```
     @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        socketManger.onDestroy()
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Comment: for instant messages , we can't relay on firebase notification . some of them are not delivered. as I searched before  background service, job schedule ,alarm manager, work manager does not work for instant messaging.

Answer (score 1):

You can start it from a custom Application class in onCreate method if you want the service to be started immediately after the app is launched.

Or you you can start it from any Activity eg. from onCreate method in case you want to start the service from certain activity.

Or you can start from BroadcastReceiver when device is booted. In this case use BOOT_COMPLETED action:

To start your service just use this code, anywhere you want to start your service:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, SocketService.class);


if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    context.startForegroundService(intent);
} else {
    context.startService(intent);
}
```